# How to assign value from url xml response to a variable in visual studio?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlhttprequest

I have a section of code that looks at the URL "https://freegeoip.net/xml/" and creates a XML Document. The xml from that URL looks like:

```
<Response>
    <IP>111.11.1.111</IP>
    <CountryCode>GB</CountryCode>
    <CountryName>United Kingdom</CountryName>
    <RegionCode>ENG</RegionCode>
    <RegionName>England</RegionName>
    <City></City>
    <ZipCode></ZipCode>
    <TimeZone>Europe/London</TimeZone>
    <Latitude>22</Latitude>
    <Longitude>0.9</Longitude>
    <MetroCode>0</MetroCode>
</Response>
```

I can see that there is a InnXML and a OuterXML that has the field and the values.

```
string url = @"https://freegeoip.net/xml/";
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(url);
```

I would like to assign certain field of this XML Document to variables such as:
-RegionName
-City
-Latitude
-Longitude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to get the specific properties with `SelectSingleNode`

```
XmlNode node = xmlDoc .SelectSingleNode("//Response//RegionName");
var regionName = node.InnerText;
```

The other one is to deserialize the xml to object:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response));
var stringReader = new StringReader(thexml);
Response response = (Response)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);


public class Response
{
    public string IP { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string RegionCode { get; set; }
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string TimeZone { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
    public string MetroCode { get; set; }
}
```

Now you have everything you need already in the `response` variable.

**Update**

To get the xml from a url:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader (URLString);
Response response = (Response)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to implement the deserialize version in your answer. but i keep getting an error at `Location location = (Location)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);`. In the `new StringReader` should that be `xmlDoc`?

Comment: Oh, no i'm sorry. that would be the xml string it self. you need a stream for the deserialze. you can use: `FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fs);serializer.Deserialize(reader);`

Comment: Sorry I'm still new to this. Where do i get the file name. the XML is taken from a URL. and in what order is this section of code meant to be run.

Comment: Workings perfectly. Thank you!